# Android app fails when "checkJNI" enabled. How to enable "NewGlobalRef" pointers in JNI java code?

Tags: android, android-ndk, dalvik

I have a complex app built using android-ndk-r9c and current android sdk, which fails when checkjni is enabled, as it is by default in dalvik Virtual-machine on most modern (post ice-cream-sandwich, ie. 4.0.0) android devices.  My app runs fine on the emulator, if one runs "adb -e shell stop / adb -e shell setprop dalvik.vm.checkjni false / adb -e shell start", but crashes with (checkJNI app bug) error, as the JNI initiating java code is using local (not "global") pointers.

This dalvik virtual machine architecture change happened a couple of years ago, and is noted in some "JNI tips" files I've found, but my attempts to fiddle about with the "GLSurfaceView_SDL.java" code to globalize the pointers has been point(er)less.  (I am not a c++ master, not even a novice...)

I've attached two files.  First shows the two "adb logcat" fragments, first one where the app starts and runs and exits ok, second, where "checkjni" is enabled, and it crashes the "dalvik" virtual machine, claiming "stale local pointer".  It has been indicated to me that I cannot tweak the app to disable "checkJNI" reference checking.

So, Im stopped. The code that triggers "stale local pointer" reference is inside GLSurfaceView_SDL.java, and I've attached the code for "class GLThread".

This is probably not a difficult fix for an experienced c++ expert. I fiddled about, making the "mGL" handle public, as it is at "mRenderer.onDrawFrame(mGL);" where
the bad local reference is indicated in my attached logcat file.
((logcat output:)  GLSurfaceView_SDL$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView_SDL.java:946).

My attempts to use "NewGlobalRef" from java, to make a global pointer were unsuccessful.
Suggestions appreciated.
 - Rus.

Two files: 1) Logcat output of emulator, shows app runs ok, 2nd: "checkjni true", and the dalvik VM crash.
2) Code fragment for "class GLTHread", from "GLSurfaceView_SDL.java" JNI code, used to set up a rendering surface, and pass control to native code.

---

```
Output of "logcat", from 7-inch WSVGA Android Emulator, without checkJNI "feature" enabled.
[ App works *perfectly*, passes significant regression tests, & does no obvious harm... :) ]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I/ActivityManager( 1133): Start proc org.gemesys.android.dosbox for activity org.gemesys.android.dosbox/.MainActivity: pid=1946 uid=10052 gids={50052, 3003, 1028, 1015}
D/dalvikvm( 1946): Late-enabling CheckJNI
I/dalvikvm( 1946): Enabling JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 5...
V/PhoneStatusBar( 1184): setLightsOn(true)
I/Choreographer( 1133): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/dalvikvm( 1946): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/org.gemesys.android.dosbox-1/libsdl-1.2.so 0xb3d8a990
D/dalvikvm( 1946): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/org.gemesys.android.dosbox-1/libsdl_mixer.so 0xb3d8a990
D/dalvikvm( 1946): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/org.gemesys.android.dosbox-1/libsdl_net.so 0xb3d8a990
D/dalvikvm( 1946): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/org.gemesys.android.dosbox-1/libsdl_sound.so 0xb3d8a990
I/System.out( 1946): libSDL: Settings.Load(): enter
I/System.out( 1946): libSDL: Settings.Load(): loaded settings successfully
V/SDL     ( 1946): GLSurfaceView_SDL::onResume()
I/System.out( 1946): libSDL: DemoGLSurfaceView.onResume(): mRenderer.mGlSurfaceCreated false mRenderer.mPaused false
V/SDL     ( 1946): GLSurfaceView_SDL::EglHelper::start(): creating GL context
V/SDL     ( 1946): GLSurfaceView_SDL::EglHelper::createSurface(): creating GL context
D/gralloc_goldfish( 1946): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
I/System.out( 1946): libSDL: DemoRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(): paused false mFirstTimeStart true
I/libSDL  ( 1946): Physical screen resolution is 1024x552, virtual screen 1024x552
D/dalvikvm( 1946): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/org.gemesys.android.dosbox-1/libapplication.so 0xb3d8a990
D/dalvikvm( 1946): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/org.gemesys.android.dosbox-1/libsdl_main.so 0xb3d8a990
I/ActivityManager( 1133): Displayed org.gemesys.android.dosbox/.MainActivity: +4s275ms
D/dalvikvm( 1946): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 53K, 15% free 2981K/3500K, paused 106ms, total 106ms
D/dalvikvm( 1946): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 59K, 15% free 2985K/3500K, paused 183ms, total 183ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 1946): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.040MB for 66973-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm( 1946): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 35ms
I/System.out( 1946): libSDL: setting envvar LANGUAGE to 'en_US'
I/System.out( 1946): libSDL: accelerometer start required: false
I/System.out( 1946): [MCL Debug]: DemoRenderer calling nativeInit with: Glbl.Datadir=> /data/data/org.gemesys.android.dosbox/files and Glbls.CmdLine => dosbox -conf /data/data/org.gemesys.android.dosbox/files/.dosbox/dosbox-0.74.conf Vidcode=> 0
I/libSDL  ( 1946): Changing curdir to "/data/data/org.gemesys.android.dosbox/files"
I/libSDL  ( 1946): Calling SDL_main("dosbox -conf /data/data/org.gemesys.android.dosbox/files/.dosbox/dosbox-0.74.conf")

I/libSDL  ( 1946): param 0 = "dosbox"

I/libSDL  ( 1946): param 1 = "-conf"

I/libSDL  ( 1946): param 2 = "/data/data/org.gemesys.android.dosbox/files/.dosbox/dosbox-0.74.conf"

I/dosbox  ( 1946): conf read:/data/data/org.gemesys.android.dosbox/files/.dosbox/dosbox-0.74.conf

I/libSDL  ( 1946): SDL_SetVideoMode(): application requested mode 640x400 OpenGL 0     
E/libSDL  ( 1946): ERROR: Getting the swap interval is not supported
E/libSDL  ( 1946): ERROR: GL_GetAttribute not supported

I/ARMAssembler( 1946): generated scanline__00000177:03010104_00008004_00000000 [100 ipp] (122 ins) at [0xa8ac71f0:0xa8ac73d8] in 0 ns

I/ARMAssembler( 1946): generated scanline__00000177:03545404_00009007_00000000 [144 ipp] (167 ins) at [0xa8ac73e0:0xa8ac767c] in 0 ns

I/ARMAssembler( 1946): generated scanline__00000177:03545404_00009006_00000000 [ 83 ipp] (106 ins) at [0xa8ac7680:0xa8ac7828] in 0 ns

I/ARMAssembler( 1946): generated scanline__00000177:03545404_00009004_00000000 [136 ipp] (159 ins) at [0xa8ac7830:0xa8ac7aac] in 0 ns

I/libSDL  ( 1946): ANDROIDAUD_OpenAudio(): app requested audio bytespersample 2 freq 22050 channels 2 samples 1024

I/libSDL  ( 1946): ANDROIDAUD_OpenAudio(): app opened audio bytespersample 2 freq 22050 channels 2 bufsize 4096

I/dosbox  ( 1946): command:AUTOEXEC.BAT
I/dosbox  ( 1946): external command:AUTOEXEC.BAT
I/dosbox  ( 1946): command fullname:AUTOEXEC.BAT
I/dosbox  ( 1946): command:SET   
I/dosbox  ( 1946): command:mount
I/dosbox  ( 1946): external command:mount
I/dosbox  ( 1946): command fullname:mount.COM
I/dosbox  ( 1946): command:c:
I/dosbox  ( 1946): external command:c:
I/libSDL  ( 1946): SDL_SetVideoMode(): application requested mode 640x400 OpenGL 0 HW 1

E/libSDL  ( 1946): ERROR: Setting the swap interval is not supported
E/libSDL  ( 1946): ERROR: Getting the swap interval is not supported
E/libSDL  ( 1946): ERROR: GL_GetAttribute not supported

I/ARMAssembler( 1946): generated scanline__00000177:03010144_00008007_00000000 [104 ipp] (126 ins) at [0xa8ac7ab0:0xa8ac7ca8] in 0 ns

I/ARMAssembler( 1946): generated scanline__00000177:03545444_00009007_00000000 [158 ipp] (212 ins) at [0xa8ac7cb0:0xa8ac8000] in 0 ns

I/dosbox  ( 1946): command:dir
I/dosbox  ( 1946): command:exit
E/libSDL  ( 1946): ERROR: Invalid window
I/libSDL  ( 1946): quitting...

I/libSDL  ( 1946): quit OK

I/AndroidRuntime( 1946): VM exiting with result code 0, cleanup skipped.
I/WindowState( 1133): WIN DEATH: Window{b4035050 u0 org.gemesys.android.dosbox/org.gemesys.android.dosbox.MainActivity}

W/WindowManager( 1133): Force-removing child win Window{b40a9a88 u0 SurfaceView} from container Window{b4035050 u0 org.gemesys.android.dosbox/org.gemesys.android.dosbox.MainActivity}
I/ActivityManager( 1133): Process org.gemesys.android.dosbox (pid 1946) has died.
W/ActivityManager( 1133): Force removing ActivityRecord{b3ff0968 u0 org.gemesys.android.dosbox/.MainActivity t4}: app died, no saved state

------------- end of first logcat section, where the app runs OK. ---------------



--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2nd Output of "logcat", from Android Emulator, *WITH* checkJNI error checking enabled.
This appears to match the logcat results from my physical Android tablet, a "Digital2", running Android 4.1.1
[The App now crashes the "Dalvik VM", no visible output appears,says bad pointer... ]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I/ActivityManager( 1991): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=org.gemesys.android.dosbox/.MainActivity} from pid 2149

E/SoundPool( 1991): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
W/AudioService( 1991): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
W/AudioService( 1991): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
D/gralloc ( 1972): Registering a buffer in the process that created it. This may cause memory ordering problems.
E/libEGL  ( 1972): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/SurfaceFlinger( 1972): glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error 315705578
E/SurfaceFlinger( 1972): got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
E/libEGL  ( 1972): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
W/WindowManager( 1991): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (343x201) to layer 21005
I/Choreographer( 2149): Skipped 67 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/ActivityManager( 1991): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{b3f96040 u0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher t1}
I/ActivityManager( 1991): Start proc org.gemesys.android.dosbox for activity org.gemesys.android.dosbox/.MainActivity: pid=2482 uid=10052 gids={50052, 3003, 1028, 1015}
D/dalvikvm( 2482): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
I/dalvikvm( 2482): CheckJNI enabled: not enabling JNI app bug workarounds.
D/dalvikvm( 1991): GC_CONCURRENT freed 746K, 18% free 6154K/7500K, paused 110ms+39ms, total 669ms
D/CountryDetector( 1991): The first listener is added
V/PhoneStatusBar( 2043): setLightsOn(true)
I/ARMAssembler( 1972): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00009002_00000000 [127 ipp] (149 ins) at [0xb5bed680:0xb5bed8d4] in 0 ns
I/Choreographer( 2043): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/ARMAssembler( 1972): generated scanline__00000077:03010104_00008002_00000000 [ 89 ipp] (110 ins) at [0xb5bed8e0:0xb5beda98] in 0 ns
D/dalvikvm( 2482): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/org.gemesys.android.dosbox-1/libsdl-1.2.so 0xb3d06d70
D/dalvikvm( 2482): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/org.gemesys.android.dosbox-1/libsdl_mixer.so 0xb3d06d70
D/dalvikvm( 2482): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/org.gemesys.android.dosbox-1/libsdl_mixer.so 0xb3d06d70, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 2482): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/org.gemesys.android.dosbox-1/libsdl_net.so 0xb3d06d70
D/dalvikvm( 2482): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/org.gemesys.android.dosbox-1/libsdl_sound.so 0xb3d06d70
D/dalvikvm( 2482): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/org.gemesys.android.dosbox-1/libsdl_sound.so 0xb3d06d70, skipping init
I/System.out( 2482): libSDL: Settings.Load(): enter
V/MmsConfig( 2465): mnc/mcc: 310260
V/MmsConfig( 2465): tag: bool value: enabledMMS - true
V/MmsConfig( 2465): tag: int value: maxMessageSize - 307200
V/MmsConfig( 2465): tag: int value: maxImageHeight - 480
V/MmsConfig( 2465): tag: int value: maxImageWidth - 640
V/MmsConfig( 2465): tag: int value: defaultSMSMessagesPerThread - 10000
V/MmsConfig( 2465): tag: int value: defaultMMSMessagesPerThread - 1000
V/MmsConfig( 2465): tag: int value: minMessageCountPerThread - 10
V/MmsConfig( 2465): tag: int value: maxMessageCountPerThread - 5000
V/MmsConfig( 2465): tag: string value: uaProfUrl - http://www.google.com/oha/rdf/ua-profile-kila.xml
V/MmsConfig( 2465): tag: int value: recipientLimit - -1
V/MmsConfig( 2465): tag: bool value: enableMultipartSMS - true
V/MmsConfig( 2465): tag: int value: smsToMmsTextThreshold - -1
V/MmsConfig( 2465): tag: bool value: enableSlideDuration - true
V/MmsConfig( 2465): tag: int value: maxMessageTextSize - -1
I/System.out( 2482): libSDL: Settings.Load(): loaded settings successfully

V/SDL     ( 2482): GLSurfaceView_SDL::onResume()
I/System.out( 2482): libSDL: DemoGLSurfaceView.onResume(): mRenderer.mGlSurfaceCreated false mRenderer.mPaused false
D/dalvikvm( 2482): GC_CONCURRENT freed 302K, 12% free 2819K/3192K, paused 16ms+10ms, total 460ms

V/SDL     ( 2482): GLSurfaceView_SDL::EglHelper::start(): creating GL context

I/Choreographer( 2482): Skipped 65 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
V/SDL     ( 2482): GLSurfaceView_SDL::EglHelper::createSurface(): creating GL context
D/gralloc_goldfish( 2482): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
I/System.out( 2482): libSDL: DemoRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(): paused false mFirstTimeStart true
I/libSDL  ( 2482): Physical screen resolution is 1024x552, virtual screen 1024x552
D/dalvikvm( 2482): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/org.gemesys.android.dosbox-1/libapplication.so 0xb3d06d70
D/dalvikvm( 2482): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/org.gemesys.android.dosbox-1/libapplication.so 0xb3d06d70, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 2482): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/org.gemesys.android.dosbox-1/libsdl_main.so 0xb3d06d70
D/dalvikvm( 2482): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/org.gemesys.android.dosbox-1/libsdl_main.so 0xb3d06d70, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 2482): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 75K, 17% free 3002K/3588K, paused 43ms, total 43ms
D/MobileDataStateTracker( 1991): default: setEnableFailFastMobileData(enabled=0)
D/dalvikvm( 2482): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 169K, 16% free 3018K/3588K, paused 72ms, total 72ms
D/dalvikvm( 2482): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 95K, 16% free 3022K/3588K, paused 42ms, total 42ms

I/ActivityManager( 1991): Displayed org.gemesys.android.dosbox/.MainActivity: +6s92ms
D/dalvikvm( 2482): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 124K, 18% free 3052K/3700K, paused 273ms, total 273ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 2482): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.179MB for 140576-byte allocation

D/ConnectivityService( 1991): stopUsingNetworkFeature: teardown net 0: enableHIPRI
I/System.out( 2482): libSDL: setting envvar LANGUAGE to 'en_US'
I/System.out( 2482): libSDL: accelerometer start required: false

D/MobileDataStateTracker( 1991): hipri: Broadcast received: android.intent.action.ANY_DATA_STATE apnType=hipri

I/System.out( 2482): [MCL Debug]: DemoRenderer calling nativeInit with: Glbl.Datadir=> /data/data/org.gemesys.android.dosbox/files and Glbls.CmdLine => dosbox -conf /data/data/org.gemesys.android.dosbox/files/.dosbox/dosbox-0.74.conf Vidcode=> 0

I/libSDL  ( 2482): Changing curdir to "/data/data/org.gemesys.android.dosbox/files"
I/libSDL  ( 2482): Calling SDL_main("dosbox -conf /data/data/org.gemesys.android.dosbox/files/.dosbox/dosbox-0.74.conf")
I/libSDL  ( 2482): param 0 = "dosbox"
I/libSDL  ( 2482): param 1 = "-conf"
I/libSDL  ( 2482): param 2 = "/data/data/org.gemesys.android.dosbox/files/.dosbox/dosbox-0.74.conf"

D/MobileDataStateTracker( 1991): hipri: Received state=DISCONNECTED, old=CONNECTED, reason=dataDisabled
D/MobileDataStateTracker( 1991): hipri: setDetailed state, old =CONNECTED and new state=DISCONNECTED
D/ConnectivityService( 1991): ConnectivityChange for mobile_hipri: DISCONNECTED/DISCONNECTED
E/logwrapper( 2506): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
E/SecondaryTablController(   48): ip route del failed: /system/bin/ip route del 10.0.2.2/32 via 0.0.0.0 dev eth0 table 60

W/FrameworkListener(   48): Handler 'interface' error (No such device)
I/dosbox  ( 2482): conf read:/data/data/org.gemesys.android.dosbox/files/.dosbox/dosbox-0.74.conf
E/logwrapper( 2508): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
E/SecondaryTablController(   48): ip route del failed: /system/bin/ip route del 0.0.0.0/0 via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0 table 60
W/FrameworkListener(   48): Handler 'interface' error (No such device)
I/libSDL  ( 2482): SDL_SetVideoMode(): application requested mode 640x400 OpenGL 0 HW 0
E/libSDL  ( 2482): ERROR: Setting the swap interval is not supported
E/libSDL  ( 2482): ERROR: Getting the swap interval is not supported
E/libSDL  ( 2482): ERROR: GL_GetAttribute not supported

D/Nat464Xlat( 1991): requiresClat: netType=5, hasIPv4Address=true
D/MobileDataStateTracker( 1991): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)

I/ARMAssembler( 2482): generated scanline__00000177:03010104_00008004_00000000 [100 ipp] (122 ins) at [0xa8b4a1f0:0xa8b4a3d8] in 20000000 ns
I/ARMAssembler( 2482): generated scanline__00000177:03545404_00009007_00000000 [144 ipp] (167 ins) at [0xa8b4a3e0:0xa8b4a67c] in 0 ns
I/ARMAssembler( 2482): generated scanline__00000177:03545404_00009006_00000000 [ 83 ipp] (106 ins) at [0xa8b4a680:0xa8b4a828] in 10000000 ns

E/dalvikvm( 2482): JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale local reference 0x20300001
W/dalvikvm( 2482): JNI WARNING: 0x20300001 is not a valid JNI reference (CallIntMethod)

W/dalvikvm( 2482):              in Lorg/gemesys/android/dosbox/DemoRenderer;.nativeInit:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)V (CallIntMethod)

I/dalvikvm( 2482): "GLThread" prio=5 tid=11 RUNNABLE

I/dalvikvm( 2482):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0xb3d5ebd8 self=0xb807fd30
I/dalvikvm( 2482):   | sysTid=2502 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=-1207434872
I/dalvikvm( 2482):   | state=R schedstat=( 1720000000 2570000000 459 ) utm=159 stm=13 core=0
I/dalvikvm( 2482):   at org.gemesys.android.dosbox.DemoRenderer.nativeInit(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm( 2482):   at org.gemesys.android.dosbox.DemoRenderer.onDrawFrame(Video.java:230)
I/dalvikvm( 2482):   at org.gemesys.android.dosbox.GLSurfaceView_SDL$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView_SDL.java:946)
I/dalvikvm( 2482): 

E/dalvikvm( 2482): VM aborting

F/libc    ( 2482): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000009b2 (code=-6), thread 2502 (GLThread)
I/DEBUG   (   49): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (   49): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic:4.4.2/KK/938007:eng/test-keys'

I/DEBUG   (   49): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   (   49): pid: 2482, tid: 2502, name: GLThread  >>> org.gemesys.android.dosbox <<<
I/DEBUG   (   49): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
E/NetdConnector( 1991): NDC Command {57 bandwidth gettetherstats} took too long (741ms)
D/Mms:app ( 2465): cancelNotification
I/DEBUG   (   49):     r0 00000000  r1 000009c6  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   49):     r4 00000006  r5 00000016  r6 000009c6  r7 0000010c
I/DEBUG   (   49):     r8 b5ad480c  r9 b5ad560f  sl b5af51f0  fp b5ad57cb
I/DEBUG   (   49):     ip b5ad5603  sp ab6a1230  lr b6ed3ead  pc b6ee2e20  cpsr 00000010
I/DEBUG   (   49):     d0  3f7f128d00002100  d1  3f8000003f800000
I/DEBUG   (   49):     d2  3f8000003f800000  d3  bf8000003a800000
I/DEBUG   (   49):     d4  bf8000003f800000  d5  3b0000003f800000
I/DEBUG   (   49):     scr 60000010
I/DEBUG   (   49): 
I/DEBUG   (   49): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (   49):     #00  pc 00021e20  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
I/DEBUG   (   49):     #01  pc 00012ea9  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+48)
I/DEBUG   (   49):     #02  pc 000130bd  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
I/DEBUG   (   49):     #03  pc 00011df3  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   49):     #04  pc 000216d4  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
I/DEBUG   (   49):     #05  pc 00045be7  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmAbort+78)
I/DEBUG   (   49):     #06  pc 00038b1b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   49):     #07  pc 000399e7  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   49):     #08  pc 000402af  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   49):     #09  pc 00026d55  /data/app-lib/org.gemesys.android.dosbox-1/libsdl-1.2.so (SDL_ANDROID_CallJavaSwapBuffers+180)
I/DEBUG   (   49):     #10  pc 00025d67  /data/app-lib/org.gemesys.android.dosbox-1/libsdl-1.2.so
I/DEBUG   (   49):     #11  pc 0001ff25  /data/app-lib/org.gemesys.android.dosbox-1/libsdl-1.2.so (SDL_Flip+224)
I/DEBUG   (   49):     #12  pc 0015dda5  /data/app-lib/org.gemesys.android.dosbox-1/libapplication.so
I/DEBUG   (   49): 
D/Tethering( 1991): MasterInitialState.processMessage what=

E/NativeCrashListener( 1991):   at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener.run(NativeCrashListener.java:138)

E/NetdConnector( 1991): NDC Command {59 bandwidth removeiquota eth0} took too long (1555ms)

I/BootReceiver( 1991): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_07 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)

I/ActivityManager( 1991): Process org.gemesys.android.dosbox (pid 2482) has died.

I/WindowState( 1991): WIN DEATH: Window{b4097048 u0 org.gemesys.android.dosbox/org.gemesys.android.dosbox.MainActivity}

D/Zygote  ( 1973): Process 2482 terminated by signal (6)

W/WindowManager( 1991): Force-removing child win Window{b4099b68 u0 SurfaceView} from container Window{b4097048 u0 org.gemesys.android.dosbox/org.gemesys.android.dosbox.MainActivity}
W/ActivityManager( 1991): Force removing ActivityRecord{b4035dd0 u0 org.gemesys.android.dosbox/.MainActivity t2}: app died, no saved state

 -------- end of first second sample, where app crashes and dies.   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------- note "dalvik" reporting that say:  
--------------> D/dalvikvm( 2482): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
--------------> I/dalvikvm( 2482): CheckJNI enabled: not enabling JNI app bug workarounds
-------- Any for app to enable "JNI app bug workarounds", that "dalvik"has turned off ???
-------- So far, the current answer is simply:  "No."    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Code:

```
    /**
     * A generic GL Thread. Takes care of initializing EGL and GL. Delegates to
     * a Renderer instance to do the actual drawing. Can be configured to render
     * continuously or on request.
     * 
     */
    class GLThread extends Thread implements SwapBuffersCallback {
        GLThread(Renderer renderer) {
            super();
            mDone = false;
            mWidth = 0;
            mHeight = 0;
            mRequestRender = true;
            mRenderMode = RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY;
            mRenderer = renderer;
            mRenderer.setSwapBuffersCallback(this);
            setName("GLThread");
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            /*
             * When the android framework launches a second instance of an
             * activity, the new instance's onCreate() method may be called
             * before the first instance returns from onDestroy().
             * 
             * This semaphore ensures that only one instance at a time accesses
             * EGL.
             */
            try {
                sEglSemaphore.acquire();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }

            mEglHelper = new EglHelper();
            // mEglHelper.start();
            mNeedStart = true;
            mSizeChanged = true;
            SwapBuffers();

            mRenderer.onDrawFrame(mGL);       /* <---------------- fails here, I think */

            mEglHelper.finish();

            /*
             * synchronized (sGLThreadManager) { stopEglLocked(); }
             * sGLThreadManager.threadExiting(this);
             */

            sEglSemaphore.release();
        }

        public boolean SwapBuffers() {

            boolean tellRendererSurfaceCreated = false;
            boolean tellRendererSurfaceChanged = false;

            /*
             * This is our main activity thread's loop, we go until asked to
             * quit.
             */
            try {

                /*
                 * Update the asynchronous state (window size)
                 */
                while (true) { // Loop until we're re-created GL context and
                                // successfully called swap()

                    int w, h;
                    boolean changed = false;
                    synchronized (this) {
                        if (mPaused) {
                            mRenderer.onSurfaceDestroyed();
                            mEglHelper.finish();
                            mNeedStart = true;
                            if (Globals.NonBlockingSwapBuffers)
                                return false;
                        }
                        while (needToWait()) {
                            // Log.v("SDL", "GLSurfaceView_SDL::run(): paused");
                            wait();
                        }
                        if (mDone) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        // changed = mSizeChanged;
                        w = mWidth;
                        h = mHeight;
                        mSizeChanged = false;
                        mRequestRender = false;
                    }
                    if (mNeedStart) {
                        mEglHelper.start();
                        tellRendererSurfaceCreated = true;
                        changed = true;
                        mNeedStart = false;
                    }
                    if (changed) {
/* MCL note.  This is where mGL is set */
                        mGL = (GL10) mEglHelper.createSurface(getHolder());
                        tellRendererSurfaceChanged = true;
                    }
                    if (tellRendererSurfaceCreated) {
                        mRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(mGL, mEglHelper.mEglConfig);
                        tellRendererSurfaceCreated = false;
                    }
                    if (tellRendererSurfaceChanged) {
                        mRenderer.onSurfaceChanged(mGL, w, h);
                        tellRendererSurfaceChanged = false;
                    }
                    /*
                     * Once we're done with GL, we need to call swapBuffers() to
                     * instruct the system to display the rendered frame
                     */
                    if (mEglHelper.swap())
                        return true;
                    // We've lost GL context - recreate it
                    mRenderer.onSurfaceDestroyed();
                    mEglHelper.finish();
                    mNeedStart = true;
                    if (Globals.NonBlockingSwapBuffers)
                        return false;
                }

            } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private boolean needToWait() {
            if (mDone) {
                return false;
            }

            if (mPaused || (!mHasSurface)) {
                return true;
            }

            if ((mWidth > 0)
                    && (mHeight > 0)
                    && (mRequestRender || (mRenderMode == RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY))) {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public void setRenderMode(int renderMode) {
            if (!((RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY <= renderMode) && (renderMode <= RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY))) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("renderMode");
            }
            synchronized (this) {
                mRenderMode = renderMode;
                if (renderMode == RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY) {
                    notify();
                }
            }
        }

        public int getRenderMode() {
            synchronized (this) {
                return mRenderMode;
            }
        }

        public void requestRender() {
            synchronized (this) {
                mRequestRender = true;
                notify();
            }
        }

        public void surfaceCreated() {
            synchronized (this) {
                mHasSurface = true;
                notify();
            }
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed() {
            synchronized (this) {
                mHasSurface = false;
                notify();
            }
        }


        public void requestExitAndWait() {
            // don't call this from GLThread thread or it is a guaranteed
            // deadlock!
            synchronized (this) {
                mDone = true;
                notify();
            }
            try {
                join();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Queue an "event" to be run on the GL rendering thread.
         * 
         * @param r
         *            the runnable to be run on the GL rendering thread.
         */
        public void queueEvent(Runnable r) {
            synchronized (this) {
                mEventQueue.add(r);
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private Runnable getEvent() {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (mEventQueue.size() > 0) {
                    return mEventQueue.remove(0);
                }

            }
            return null;
        }

        private boolean mDone;
        private boolean mPaused;
        private boolean mHasSurface;
        private int mWidth;
        private int mHeight;
        private int mRenderMode;
        private boolean mRequestRender;
        private Renderer mRenderer;
        private ArrayList<Runnable> mEventQueue = new ArrayList<Runnable>();
        private EglHelper mEglHelper;
        private GL10 mGL = null;
        private boolean mNeedStart = false;
    }
```

-- end of code --

Comment: The JNI failures happen in the native code, not the Java code.  Looking at the stack trace, `SDL_ANDROID_CallJavaSwapBuffers` is invoking the `CallIntMethod` function with a stale reference.  Assuming the SDL code isn't broken, it's likely some bit of native code in `libapplication.so` is attempting to use a stale reference.  If you can identify the source line in `libsdl-1.2.so` with `addr2line` it should be straightforward to track down.

Comment: Thanx for the "addr2line" hint, it is a useful utility.  Also, I realize now "NewGlobalRef" is called from within c/c++.  I rebuilt the app using Android-8, by running the SDK "android" utility, with "update project", and including parameter "--target=andriod-8".  That enables a dalvik-VM option "JNI app bug workarounds".  I still have the curious situation where the emulator - with "checkjni" set to "false" - runs the app flawlessly, but the app, built now with target=android-8, fails on Android device, despite the device logcat reporting that checkjni is disabled, and workarounds enabled.